# Menus don't appear in admin area / WordPress Multisite

Tags: menus, multisite

I have a WordPress multisite with different subdomains. My problem is, that I can´t edit the menus. The number of the existing menus is displayed left under the languages part. But I always get the message: "Build your first menu". Does anyone get the same problem?[image]

Comment: Looks like maybe you're using Max Mega Menu which could have something to do with this. You could try disabling it to see if it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already tried that, but unfortunately no change.